# React: Programmatically opening modals (and cleaning up automatically)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a site with lots of modals which can be opened from anywhere (for example `LoginModal`). The challenge I'm running into is if I open one programmatically with something like `ReactDOM.render`, how do I clean it up automatically when the parent component is unmounted without putting it (and all possible modals) in the template.

For example, something like this to open it:

```
openLoginModal() {
  ReactDOM.render(<LoginModal />, document.body);
}
```

`LoginModal` can clean itself up when closed. However, if the DOM from the component which opened it is unmounted, how do I let `LoginModal` know to unmount as well.

One thought I've had is to use an Rx.Subject to notify it when to unmount, but this also sounds like a bit of a wrong approach and a possible anti-pattern.

For example:

```
// modules/User.js
openLoginModal(unmountSubj) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<LoginModal />, container);
  unmountSubj.subscribe(() => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  });
}

// components/RandomView.jsx
unmountSubject = new Rx.Subject();
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unmountSubject.next();
}
login() {
  User.openLoginModal(this.unmountSubject);
}
```

I'd like to avoid having all the possible modal components in each JSX template they might be used in.

How would you approach this?

Comment: You can't render all your possible Modals in one single DOM node, and just show/hide them with state, and use `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);` on that single node when appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Rendering all the modals when the app loads could cause the app to run slower. We're trying to only load what we need when we need it.

Comment: Alright. I don't know what built step you are using, but you might be able to leverage [`import`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) so that you can write code as if it were just one bundle, but Webpack will load the code split Modals just when needed.

Comment: We're using webpack, and the plan would be to `import` the module and then render & inject it into the dom when needed.

Comment: I don't believe code splitting into different bundles helps resolve the challenge I'm trying to solve.

Comment: If you just want to load the code that should be used, and you want to make life easier by using one single container to use `ReactDOM.render` on, I think code splitting would make that very smooth.

Comment: @Tholle, maybe I'm missing something you're saying, but my challenge is more about cleaning up and unmounting when navigating away from where the modal was used. By default when a component is a child of another, this happens automatically, however, when it's rendered/injected manually, it will not be unmounted automatically when the parent nodes are removed.

Comment: Yes, my point is just that it will most likely make life easier for you if you just have one single "modal container" that contains all the different modals in your app, and e.g. `openLoginModal` would just change a variable in the component state, `this.state.isLoginModalOpen && <LoginModal />`. That way you just have one single DOM node to worry about for all your modals, and all other cleanup would happen automatically like you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I've come up with so far: There's a modal manager module, which will render a modal into the DOM (via `ReactDOM.render`) and return a function which will unmount it.

Here's a simplified version:

```
// modalManager.js
export default modalManager = {
  openModal(modalClass, props) {
    // Create container for the modal to be rendered into
    const renderContainer = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(renderContainer);

    // Create & render component
    const modalInst = React.createElement(modalClass, { ...props, renderContainer });
    ReactDOM.render(modalInst, renderContainer);

    // Return unmounting function
    return () => this.unmountModal(renderContainer);
  },

  unmountModal(renderContainer) {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(renderContainer);
    renderContainer.parentNode.removeChild(renderContainer);
  },
}

// TestThing.jsx
class TestThing extends React.Component {

  unmountLogin = null;

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unmountLogin();
  }

  login() {
    this.unmountLogin = modalManager.openModal(Login, {});
  }
}
```

You'll also notice that `renderContainer` is passed to the modal component. This way the modal can call `modalManager.unmountModal` itself when closed.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

In my current React project, I've addressed this by having a multilayered component architecture.

```
<App>
    // the standard starting point for React apps
    <DataLayer>
        // this is where I make API calls for data that is shared between all components
        <DisplayLayer>
            // this is where I put the methods to launch display elements that are shared
            // by all components (e.g., modals, alerts, notifications, etc.)
            <Template>
                // this is the first layer that is actually outputting HTML content
                <ModuleX>
                <ModuleY>
                <ModuleZ>
                    // these modules control the main display area of the screen, they encompass
                    // major UI functions (e.g., UsersModule, TeamsModule, etc.)
                    // when one of these modules needs to launch a shared UI element (like a 
                    // modal), they call a method in the <DisplayLayer> template - this means 
                    // that if I have a commonly-used modal (like, LoginModal), it doesn't need 
                    // to be included in every one of the core modules where someone might need 
                    // to initiate a login; these modules are mounted-and-unmounted as the user 
                    // navigates through the app
```

So when the app loads, `<App>`, `<DataLayer>`, `<DisplayLayer>`, and `<Template>` all load up (and they will only load one time).  As the user navigates around, the `<ModuleX/Y/Z/etc>` components are mounted-and-unmounted, but all of the "common stuff" stays in place that was mounted/loaded in the higher layers of the app.